# Assigning Variable and Data-Retreival in two select statements with multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

I understand you cannot combine assigning of variables and data-retrieval in the same select statement. I am using two select statements which will work well when a where clause is used and a single row is returned in the select that assigns the variables. How can I make these selects work together when multiple rows are returned from the select that assigns the variables?

```
DECLARE @CompanyName NVARCHAR(40)
DECLARE @ContactName NVARCHAR(30)

SELECT @CompanyName = CompanyName,
       @ContactName = ContactName
FROM Customers

SELECT @CompanyName,@ContactName
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with the resultset from your query? If I understand you correctly, you can use either a temp table or a table variable.

Comment: I am actually doing calculations with the variables and would like the rows returned. The above is just demo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather go for a [table type variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175010.aspx) like below

```
--Declare the table variable with the columns
declare @tab table (
CompanyName NVARCHAR(40),
ContactName NVARCHAR(30)
);

-- insert into table variable
insert into @tab(CompanyName, ContactName)
SELECT CompanyName, ContactName
FROM Customers

-- select from table variable 
SELECT * from @tab;
```

Comment: That seems like a lot of extra overhead when a temp table would work just as well.

Comment: @SeanLange, some people would say going by temp table is an extra overhead.

Comment: I misread your post. I thought you were saying to use a user defined table type. Doh!!

Comment: Table variable vs temp table is a long running debate with both sides being right. :D

Comment: @SeanLange, that's correct. there are tons of article on internet based on this debate. I went through few and got confused. so, I just stopped and follow my own justification as to when to use what.

Comment: LOL I know what you mean. I don't have a hard and fast rule but generally speaking I tend to switch to a temp table if there are going to be more than 100 or so rows.

Answer (score 1):

To use a table variable, here's a really simple example based on yours:

```
declare @TableVar table (companyname varchar(40), contactname varchar(30))

insert into @TableVar
select companyname, contactname from Customers
```

Then you can select from your table variable, etc.